# Configure frontend and backend on 2 different micros in Deta.space (Express & NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code from my nodejs express app, where I serve static files from the "public" folder using `express.static` and then I deploy to a Deta microservice and it works perfect.

**DETA ROUTING DOCUMENTATION:**
https://deta.space/docs/en/basics/micros#micro-routing

This is the configuration of the Deta file that I currently use and it works fine:

```
v: 0
micros:
  - name: web
    src: .
    engine: nodejs16
    primary: true
```

Index.js:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.deta.app'
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api1', async (req, res) => {
//code
});

app.post('/api2', async (req, res) => {
//code
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });
}
```

**But I want to use a micro to serve the static files from "public" using a static engine and the index.js has a separate micro with nodejs.**

As much as I try I can't do it. Using this configuration I do serve the `public` folder in the root directory, but I get a 404 error when making any client-side request to `/api1` or `/api2`. Im using fetch on client to `exampledomain.com/api1/`

```
v: 0
micros:
  - name: web
    src: .
    engine: nodejs16
  - name: frontend
    src: public
    engine: static
    primary: true
    public: true
    serve: .
```

In summary I want to serve the `public` folder in the domain root using a **static engine** and the index.js file with the paths `api1` and `api2` with an **engine "nodejs16"**.

PS: In my local folder and to which I deploy the structure is:
[image: deta]